# Divide the dataframe1 column values with another dataframe column value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 dateframes DF1 & DF2.i want perform the division for all DF2_sale column values with DF1_Expectation and update in DF1_percentage

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Period'     : ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
               'Sale': [10 , 20, 30],
               })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Loc': ['UAE'],
               'Expectation': [98],
               })
```

Please refer attached dataframe screens
[image: DF1]

[image: DF2]

Comment: For Pandas related questions it helps everyone if you can post a [reproducible example of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) rather than a picture of some data.

Comment: @DavidBuck not only for `pandas` related question...

Comment: Are you going to update only by 'UAE' location?

Comment: Yes I want to update only by 'UAE' Location

Answer (score 1):

To apply some operation along an axis of the DataFrame you can always use `apply`. For example:

```
df1['Percentage'] = df1['Sale'].apply(lambda x: x / df2['Expectation'])
```

or, if instead of a simple division you want to count percentage:

```
df1['Percentage'] = df1['Sale'].apply(lambda x: x * df2['Expectation'] / 100)
```

Details in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Period": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"], "Sale": [10, 20, 30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Loc": ["UAE"], "Expectation": [98]})

df1['Percentage'] = df1['Sale'].apply(lambda x: x * df2['Expectation'] / 100)
print(f"df1 = {df1}")
```

output:

```
df1 =   Period  Sale  Percentage
0    Jan    10         9.8      
1    Feb    20        19.6      
2    Mar    30        29.4
```